# Two select tags. First gets parent categories, second WANT to get childs of each one depending which parent is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have only the first select up and running. Need help for the second. Can it be done only with PHP or it requires javascript or ajax? I'm using Wordpress btw.

```
function sellers_area_selection()
{
  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'seller',
   'taxonomy'  => 'nomos',
   'hide_empty'=> 0,
   'parent'    => 0
  );

  $categories = get_categories( $args );

  if ( $categories ) {
  echo '<select id="nomoi-select">';
    echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Νομοί</span></option>';

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $id = $category->term_id;
      $name = $category->name;
      echo '<option class="nomos" id="'. $id .'">'. $name .'</option>';
    }
  echo '</select>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand your comment

Comment: much cleaner to do in ajax/javascript

Comment: could you show me how?

Comment: It's too complicated for stack overflow. Google "cascading dropdown menus". Try it and then ask a question on your error.